# Cocoapod library issue: DTCoreText

Tags: ios, objective-c, dtcoretext

I posed a question earlier about this problem but I've since cleaned the project and restarted from scratch.

Im trying to use DTCoreText

1. My podfile:

> ```
> platform :iOS
> pod 'DTCoreText'
> ```

^quote since for some reason editor wouldn't let me just put code there.

2. `Other Linker Flags`: `-OjbC` `-all_load`
3. [image: Linked Frameworks]
4. [image: Project]

I get a long list of errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_htmlCreatePushParserCtxt", referenced from:
      -[DTHTMLParser parse] in libPods-DTFoundation.a(DTHTMLParser.o)
  "_htmlCtxtUseOptions", referenced from:
      -[DTHTMLParser parse] in libPods-DTFoundation.a(DTHTMLParser.o)
  "_htmlFreeParserCtxt", referenced from:
      -[DTHTMLParser dealloc] in libPods-DTFoundation.a(DTHTMLParser.o)
  "_htmlParseDocument", referenced from:
      -[DTHTMLParser parse] in libPods-DTFoundation.a(DTHTMLParser.o)
  "_xmlDetectCharEncoding", referenced from:
      -[DTHTMLParser parse] in libPods-DTFoundation.a(DTHTMLParser.o)
  "_xmlParseCharEncoding", referenced from:
      -[DTHTMLParser parse] in libPods-DTFoundation.a(DTHTMLParser.o)
  "_xmlSAX2GetColumnNumber", referenced from:
      -[DTHTMLParser columnNumber] in libPods-DTFoundation.a(DTHTMLParser.o)
  "_xmlSAX2GetLineNumber", referenced from:
      -[DTHTMLParser lineNumber] in libPods-DTFoundation.a(DTHTMLParser.o)
  "_xmlSAX2GetPublicId", referenced from:
      -[DTHTMLParser publicID] in libPods-DTFoundation.a(DTHTMLParser.o)
  "_xmlSAX2GetSystemId", referenced from:
      -[DTHTMLParser systemID] in libPods-DTFoundation.a(DTHTMLParser.o)
  "_xmlSAX2InitHtmlDefaultSAXHandler", referenced from:
      -[DTHTMLParser initWithData:encoding:] in libPods-DTFoundation.a(DTHTMLParser.o)
  "_xmlStopParser", referenced from:
      -[DTHTMLParser abortParsing] in libPods-DTFoundation.a(DTHTMLParser.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This is my first attempt at using Cocoapod, I'm probably making a noob mistake here

---

If I remove DTFoundation.a and DTCoreText.a from linked frameworks the project runs, but I get the following error:

```
-[NSConcreteMutableAttributedString initWithHTMLData:documentAttributes:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Using their sample code:

```
#import "DTCoreText.h"

NSString *html = @"<p>Some Text</p>";
NSData *data = [html dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSAttributedString *attrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithHTMLData:data
                                                           documentAttributes:NULL];
NSLog(@"%@", attrString);
```

When I updated with the podfile Jon Suggested and removed old configs/linker flags I get this error:

```
[!] The `**** [Debug]` target overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-****/Pods-****.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `**** [Release]` target overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-****/Pods-****.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.
```

How do I reset these? or is there a way to tell it to overwrite it regardless?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Works on my machine."™

Are you using the latest CocoaPods? 0.37.1 is the latest and you should use it unless you have a specific reason not to.

This Podfile worked fine for me (generated by running `pod init` in the project directory):

```
platform :ios, '8.3'

target 'DTCoreTextTest' do
  pod 'DTCoreText'
end

target 'DTCoreTextTestTests' do

end
```

With no need to add the extra `-ObjC` or `-all_load` flags.

Comment: I just installed cocoaPods today using gem so i should be running the most recent version.

Strange this though, when I ran using your podfile i got a error, posted above

Comment: Did you get rid of the extra linker flags you added? Also, you'll need to delete the configurations set by the old Podfile to use the new one.

Comment: yes, i removed the linker flags, just removed the old configs, trying again

Comment: Now i just get the unrecognized selector sent to instance error, everything else runs(happens if i include all 3 libs or just the base pod.a)

Comment: Again, that like of code works for me. `NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithHTMLData:nil documentAttributes:nil];`

Comment: Also, you shouldn't be managing the pod libraries at all. CocoaPods will create your workspace so that they're built and included automatically.

Comment: When I removed the custom linker flags somehow $(inherited) got removed. its all working now. THANKS!